# How to take value of a checkbox as 1 for checked box in jade

Tags: pug

I am using jade in which I have a checkbox in my code. When user selects a checkbox then value is send as true to the server instead of 1 while for unchecked boxes value is sent as 0. How can I pass value of checkbox as 1 when user checks the checkbox.

input.form-control(type="checkbox", name="compare_form_required", id="compare_form_required", ng-model="program.compareFormRequired")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Used ng-true-value="1" that sets the value as 1 on check of a checkbox 
So I have used it this way :

input.form-control(type="checkbox", name="compare_form_required", id="compare_form_required", ng-model="program.compareFormRequired", ng-true-value="1")

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to do so in jade, you can only do something like this afterwards to convert it :

```
var data = request.body;
if (data.yourCheckbox === 'on') {
  data.yourCheckbox = 1;
} else if (data.yourCheckbox) {
   data.yourCheckbox = 0;
}
```

Comment: I have got the solution: I Used ng-true-value="1" that sets the value as 1 on check of a checkbox

Comment: You should answer your question then. If you cannot yet, edit your question with the answer in it. Great solution btw.

Answer (score 0):

1. if(Check=="on")
2. label(for=key)= "IVA "
3. Input(name="iva" type="checkbox" id=key onchange="ivaSwitch(this.id)" 
   checked)
4. else
5. label(for=key)= "IVA "
6. Input(name="iva" type="checkbox" id=key onchange="ivaSwitch(this.id)" )